# Sorting an NSArray by a key-value relationship that is 2 levels deep

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsarray, userinfo

I have an NSArray of UILocalNotification objects that I need to sort according to a key within the UILocalNotification's userInfo property, which is an NSDictionary. I know how to sort NSArrays by a value that is one level deep, e.g., a key within an array of NSDictionaries, but two levels deep I'm lost. I want to do something like this is psuedo-code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"userInfo.personName" ascending:YES]; 
//the personName key within the userInfo NSDictionary property of a given UILocalNotification
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:&sortDescriptor count:1] autorelease];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]] autorelease];
[sortedArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try your code? Apple's document ([here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSortDescriptor/initWithKey:ascending:)) says it accepts key paths, not just keys.

Comment: I thought I had remembered that dot syntax from somewhere!